# Java Arraylist search for specific string and if found then print

Tags: java, string, search, printing, arraylist

having a problem with this java homework where I input Olympians into the array list: Name, Gold, silver, bronze medals. If the name of the olympian searched is found then print out the name and the medals he got, else print an error message. This is the code so far to input the name and medals.

```
   public class Analyser {

     private ArrayList <Olympian> olympians;

        public Analyser() {
            olympians = new ArrayList<Olympian>();    
        } 

        public void addOlympian (String name, int gold, int silver, int bronze) {
            olympians.add(new Olympian(name, gold, silver, bronze));       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well firstly you want to add some olympians!

Answer (score 0):

Before asking for help with the code itself, you need to figure out a few things:

- What parameters your `searchOlympian()` function should take.
- How you're going to find the desired `Olympian` in the `ArrayList`, given the name.
- How you're going to figure out if the `Olympian` isn't in your list.

A few hints:

- `String.equals(String otherString)` will return true if the strings are equal.
- `for (Olympian olympian : olympians)` will help you go through each `Olympian`.
- If you go through the above loop without finding the `Olympian`, then the `Olympian` isn't in the list.